# Getting a column as concatenated column from a reference table and primary id's from a Dataset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to get a concatenated data as a single column using below datasets.

Sample DS:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("a", 1,2,3),
  ("b", 4,6,5)
)).toDF("value", "id1", "id2", "id3")

+-------+-----+-----+-----+
| value | id1 | id2 | id3 |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+
| a     |   1 |   2 |   3 |
| b     |   4 |   6 |   5 |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+
```

from the Reference Dataset

```
+----+----------+--------+
| id |   descr   | parent|
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 | apple    | fruit  |
|  2 | banana   | fruit  |
|  3 | cat      | animal |
|  4 | dog      | animal |
|  5 | elephant | animal |
|  6 | Flight   | object |
+----+----------+--------+

val ref= sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1,"apple","fruit"),
  (2,"banana","fruit"),
  (3,"cat","animal"),
  (4,"dog","animal"),
  (5,"elephant","animal"),
  (6,"Flight","object"),
)).toDF("id", "descr", "parent")
```

I am trying to get the below desired OutPut

```
+-----------------------+--------------------------+
|         desc          |          parent          |
+-----------------------+--------------------------+
| apple+banana+cat/M    | fruit+fruit+animal/M     |
| dog+Flight+elephant/M | animal+object+animal/M   |
+-----------------------+--------------------------+
```

And also I need to concat only if(id2,id3) is not null. Otherwise only with id1.

I breaking my head for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exploding the first dataframe `df` and joining to `ref` with followed by `groupBy` should work as you expected

```
val dfNew = df.withColumn("id", explode(array("id1", "id2", "id3")))
  .select("id", "value")

ref.join(dfNew, Seq("id"))
  .groupBy("value")
  .agg(
    concat_ws("+", collect_list("descr")) as "desc", 
    concat_ws("+", collect_list("parent")) as "parent"
  )
  .drop("value")
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+--------------------+
|desc               |parent              |
+-------------------+--------------------+
|Flight+elephant+dog|object+animal+animal|
|apple+cat+banana   |fruit+animal+fruit  |
+-------------------+--------------------+
```